# Xmind 7.5 / 7.0 crash on startup

Tags: software-installation, crash

I'm running Elementary OS Freya.

Since last version 7.0, Xmind crash on startup.

It shows the Splash Page, open the main program, the computer to be sluggish and after some seconds (~15-30 sec).
It logout from my session (close all program), and show my login page.

on logs /home/user/.xmind/workspace-cathy/.metadata/.log

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2016-07-15 06:59:32.690
!MESSAGE Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: bundleclass://org.xmind.ui.sharing/org.xmind.ui.internal.sharing.SharingServiceStatusToolControl
!SESSION 2016-07-15 07:01:44.144 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.6.0.R-201511090408
java.version=1.7.0_101
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments: -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -data @user.home/.xmind/workspace-cathy

Tested Xmind 7.0 and same behavior spotted.

Anyone using Xmind 7.5 linux have the same behavior ?

Any suggestion to tshoot this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve my issue. After several attempts, my issue was easily solved by launching the program with elevated privilege.

on terminal :

> sudo XMind

and to make it opening as root when clicked on desktop icon / or plank dock bar

Edit file :

> /usr/share/applications/xmind.desktop

Change Line

> Exec=XMind

to

> Exec=gksudo -k -u root XMind

easy !